# How to set focus to the inner TextBox but with the blinking caret visible?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I made this control template for a WPF TextBox.

```
<Style x:Key="SearchTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Border 
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource Grey200Brush}" 
                    BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        
                        <glph:GlyphAwesome 
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Glyph="search"
                            Margin="4"
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource MyFontFamily}"
                            Foreground="{StaticResource Grey200Brush}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Visibility="{Binding ElementName=TextField, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource InverseEmptyStringToVisibilityConverter}}"
                            FontSize="13"/>

                        <TextBox
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Margin="4"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource MyFontFamily}"
                            Foreground="{StaticResource Blue900Brush}"
                            x:Name="TextField"
                            Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<TextBox 
    Name="myTextBox" 
    Text="{Binding FieldId, TargetNullValue='', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    Style="{StaticResource SearchTextBox}"
    MinWidth="150"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    Focusable="True"/>
```

It should display a search icon next a text input field. Although the search icon disappears when you start typing in the inner textbox, I am not able to display the blinking caret by using

```
MyTextField.Focus()
```

The caret appears only if I click the text box(inner one) with mouse.

What should I do here?
Somehow transfer the focus from the outed to the inner text box or?
Also how do I collapse the glyph when the text box is focused and not when you start typing?

Comment: You're taking the wrong approach. Embedding a TextBox inside a TextBox control template is not right. You should instead extract a TextBox control template using Blend for Visual Studio, and then modify it to add your icon. You can then use control template triggers to properly show/hide your icon.

Comment: If you want to show/hide the icon when the TextBox has keyboard focus, then use the IsKeyboardFocusWithin property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is wrong. It should feel odd to you to put a `TextBox` inside a `TextBox`.
The `TextBox` renders its content using a `ScrollViewer` as host. This allows for text scrolling. The content host can be any `FrameworkElement` in general. It *must* be named `PART_ContentHost`.

Always check [Microsoft Docs: Control Styles and Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-styles-and-templates) to get the default styles and templates, named parts and visual states of WPF controls. Here you also find the [TextBox ControlTemplate Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/textbox-styles-and-templates#textbox-controltemplate-example) and at the top a list of mandatory named elements that must be part of the template.

Fix your template by replacing the inner `TextBox` with a `ScrollViewer` named `PART_ContentHost`:

```
<Style x:Key="SearchTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Border 
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource Grey200Brush}" 
                    BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        
                        <glph:GlyphAwesome x:Name="SearchSymbol"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Glyph="search"
                            Margin="4"
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource MyFontFamily}"
                            Foreground="{StaticResource Grey200Brush}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            FontSize="13"/>

                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                      Grid.Column="1" 
                                      Margin="0" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="SearchSymbol"
                                Property="Visibilty"
                                Value="Collapsed" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```